# Im getting sqlite3 syntax error when trying to execute the following command in python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to make a function to drop all the tables in the current database.
This is what I have:

```
def drop_tables (self):
    cur.execute ("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")
    tlist = cur.fetchall()
    with conn:
        for t in tlist:
            cur.execute ('DROP TABLE ?;', t[0])
```

Which yields the following error:

```
File "/storage/sdcard0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/.last_tmp.py", line 170, in drop_tables
cur.execute ('DROP TABLE ?;', t[0])
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

It's a sqlite3 error, not a python error. Can I not have the cursor substitute like this? Is there any other way to achieve this; other then deleting the database?
(And I don't know if the "with" statement is required for a DROP, but I get the error regardless)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use parameters to specify any SQL keyword or database entity name.  You can only use them in place of column values.  You will need to construct the `DROP TABLE` command as an SQL string and pass the unparameterized string as the SQL command.  If the table name originates outside your application, make sure to sanitize it!

Comment: I didn't even think of just preformatting it as a string -_-. You can tell I'm over tired. And it can't be malicious as what I'm trying to insert is the name of a table, so any injected commands would have to be in the form of a created table name. Plus, even if that is possible, the db is a save for a game I'm making, so I couldn't care less at this point. Thank you!